# Swift3 ViewController cannot load normally and show black view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a **Welcome & Guide page** for an iOS app. I am using Swift 3. My problem is that when I try to show the `Main.storyboard` after  finishing the **Guide instructions**, I get a black view instead of the `Main.storyboard`:

[image]

I use `window?.rootViewController = ViewController()`in `AppDelegate.swift` to switch a new `ViewController` which is linked with the `Main.storyboard`. But I get nothing except a black view.

Comment: add code instead of image? what is difficult in that?

Comment: please also code as text additional to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used storyboard then you will have to fetch your view controller as

```
   let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_identifier_which_you_have_set_in_storyboard")
 window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

If your viewController is embedded in UINavigationController then just make this change:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController =    storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
```